# Cannot run batch file with xcopy command

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

The code in batch file is :`XCOPY "D:\hosts" "C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc" /R /Y`. But it doesn't work. cmd run like :[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you running this batch file as Administrator? You will need Administrator privileges to modify this folder.

Comment: Of course. I running as Ad, but it's doesn't work.

Comment: Change the name of the batch file

Comment: Great. I did it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output, I'd say you've called your batch file `xcopy.cmd` or `xcopy.bat.

That means, when it tries to call the *actual* `xcopy` executable, it instead calls itself in an infinitely recursive loop.

If that *is* the case, you have a couple of options:

1. Rename your batch file to something more sensible, such as `copy_hosts.cmd`, something that's not likely to clash with a real command; or
2. Make sure you call `xcopy.exe` *explicitly* from your batch file, so it goes and gets the real one.